# Autocomplete - как передать с формы ID вместо NAME?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

Пытаюсь разобраться с автокомплитом который использует плагин JQUERY, не могу разобраться чтобы передать из формы с автокомплитом не NAME, а ID-NAME полученные с бд.
Прошу не судить меня строго, а помочь... У меня с пхп плохо, а с JS -вообще полный крах ;-)

Привожу код:

```
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>



                             <form id="messageForm" action="search" metod="get">
                             <input id="autocomplete" name="city" type="text">
                             <button type="submit" id="send">Отправить</button>
                              </form>




<script>    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
                        source: [ <?php foreach($cities as $q) {

                            echo '"'.$q->city.'"'.",";} ?> ]
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: Ну судить Вас конечно строго никто не будет, но от этого не станет понятнее что конкретно Вам нужно. Что значит передать вместо name (что за name? Это name inputa в форме или что-то другое), id-name полученный из БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас на стороне пхп есть массив `$cities` каждый элемент которого представляет объект с полями `id, name`, то сначала вы преобразуете это к форме `value,label` как просит autocomplete, .

```
 $data = array_map(function($c){
               return ['value' => $c->id, 'label' => $c->name];
            }, $cities);
```

а затем кодируете в json для передачи в JS

```
 source: <?= json_encode($data) ?>,
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Думаю Ваш ответ правильный или прям совсем близко, но почему-то выбираешь город, а вместо название города в поле input появляется его id. А мне нужно, что бы название города из автокомплита отсалось в поле, а id передалось гетом

Comment: если вы обратитесь к документации, то там так и написано, что действием по умолчанию является замена на value. Так что вам следует обработать событие `select` и написать там что-то вида `function(event, ui){ $("#input").val( ui.item.label); )}`

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался;-)